Are Thunderbolt 5 enclosures backwards compatible with USB 2.0?
I am looking for an external SSD enclosure. I will most likely make one purchase only. I am conflicted between the following options:

ZikeDrive - Controller ASM2464PD

OWC Express 1M2 - Controller ASM2464PD

TREBLEET Thunderbolt 5 - Controller JHL9480


I initially decided upon ZikeDrive but since there are reports about its thermal performance not good for persistent workload resulting in throttling or even reducing the lifetime of the SSD. As a result I leaned towards OWC Express 1M2 since it is all aluminum with better thermals but the same controller which is backwards compatible to USB 2.0. Then I saw the third option which is newer technology but uses an intel controller. So I am not sure this will support connections with USB 2.0 or not. Can someone please let me know if this TREBLEET Thunderbolt 5 will still be able to connect using USB C to USB Type A cable to an older device supporting USB 2.0. I understand the speed will be slower but as long as it is compatible and can do data transfers, I am good with this.
